# JavaScript Slide without JQuery

Tags: javascript

Could someone please help me with this. First let me put up the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="FirstChild" style=" background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 50px; margin: 5px;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 window.onload = someThing;

 function someThing(){
    window.onclick = WidthChange;
 }


function WidthChange(){ 
    var presentWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("FirstChild").style.width);
    document.getElementById("FirstChild").style.width = presentWidth + 1 +"px";
    setTimeout(WidthChange(), 3000);
}
```

Now, I want to increase the width of the div by 1 px after every 3 second when the user clicks on the window. I want this to happen forever. But it doesnt work. When I click on the window, the width immediately increases. 
I know how to do it with jQuery animate() and I don't want to use that. Only Javascript please!

Comment: possible duplicate of [slide a div using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050905/slide-a-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The with immediately increases because you're not setting a timed out call to the function, but setting a timedout call to the *return value* of that widthchange function. Replace `setTimeout(WidthChange(), 3000);` with `setTimeout(WidthChange, 3000)`.
While you're at it, please also consider doing something about this:

```
presentWidth + 1 +"px";
```

You're doing two things at once here: adding ints together *and* concatenating strings. Just be clear as to which you want to do first:

```
(presentWidth +1) +"px";
```

Or just seperate this into two statements.

Lastly: convention dictates that functions that start with a capital letter are constructors, not just functions/event handlers. so perhaps change `WidthChange` to `widthChange`, too?

*Update*
The difference between `setTimeout(WidthChange, 3000)` and `setTimeout(WidthChange(), 3000)` is quite simple. JS regards `WidthChange()` as an expression, that needs to be resolved to a value (like a fracture in maths). The expression calls a function, so it can be resolved to *the return value of that function call*. Hence, the function is called immediatly, not after 3000ms. 
In the version without the parentheses, the value passed to setTimeout as first argument is a reference to a function, which is impossible to resolve further/simplify. That function is what `setTimeout` will call after the timeout has expired. Just google `setTimeout MDN` (and bookmark MDN) if this isn't clear to you.

Comment: FYI, there is no need for parentheses, because such expressions are always evaluated left-to-right. (Operator precedence does not come into play here, since it’s the same operator twice.)

Comment: Could you please explain me again the difference between setTimeout(WidthChange, 3000) and etTimeout(WidthChange(), 3000);  or give me some link where I clear my doubt about this concept!

Comment: @Navneet, the first one passes the reference to the function as parameter to setTimeout, while the second one executes the function there and then, and passes only the _return value_ of that function to setTimout (which _usually_ is not what you want – a function returning a function reference is possible, but not a typical use case.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will this code work for all browsers or should I add something to make it more compatible?

Comment: @NavneetSaini: I edited my answer to explain the difference. on the X-browser front, I can tell you that using `window.onload` like that does create [a mem-leak in IE<9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures) but as it now stands, I'd say work at it some more, until everything is in working order. Then start tweaking and refining those little things

Comment: @NavneetSaini: Glad I could help... do look into some of the trickery I use in the snippets I posted in the question on mem-leaks and closures. Especially the answer that shows how to avoid those leaks.

Answer (score 0):

**In your code-**

```
  var presentWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("FirstChild").style.width);
```

**Now time to setTimeout  -**

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('FirstChild').style.width = (presentWidth+1)+"px" },
               3000);
```